# 2048: How to continue when forced to go in the wrong direction

Tags: 2048

What's the best way to continue, if one was forced to move in the wrong direction and a 2 spawned at the opposite side of a large number row?

Example:

[image: Example situation in 2048 game]

The last state was all tiles one piece below except for the lower 2 which didn't exist. There was only one moved allowed: upwards, which created an empty row at the bottom into which a 2 spawned.

In this situation, I usually don't las any much longer, because going down again disrupts everything. What is the best way to continue?

I know different algorithms, but most of them are for machines. And the "monotonicity-smoothness-free tiles" approach doesn't work here.

Comment: This is the worst possible outcome. In all 3 other cases, I would advise down, but in this case, I'd go right and pray the new tile doesn't appear in the same spot. Repeat until the second tile is free, then go down.

Answer (score 6):

Go straight down.

If you go left or right or even up again, the small tiles will spawn under the larger tiles and you will have nothing to merge them with.

If you go down straight away you will still have **2**'s, **4**'s and **8**'s to merge with.

For example:

In this case, the only possible move is up.

[image: In this case the only move is up]

When you go up a small tile will spawn, don't worry, just go down again so that no more small tiles spawn at the bottom.

[image: When you go up...]

After you go down the small tile will still be there, but you can still continue with the game ignoring it, usually after making a few moves you will be able to get rid of it.

[image: Like this]

[image: Like this]

I used this game as an example, it works the same way with big tiles like **1024**'s, **2048**'s and even **4096**'s. It's almost never ***impossible*** to get out of a situation like this, you just need to think about each move before you do it.

Comment: It works the same way with bigger tiles, but if those bigger tiles have long tails, you're going to be in trouble. When you have a 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, and a 64 on the board, you only have 9 tiles to work with - chances are you have a couple 8s and 16s clogging it up, and condensing it into a 3x4 block will kill your game, no questions asked.