# Is tile spawning under fast movement bugged?

Tags: 2048

I am aware of 2048's spawning rules:
 spawn 2 in random empty spot 90% of the time
 spawn 4 in random empty spot 10% of the time

I have noticed it's possible to avoid [such a situation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169463/2048-how-to-continue-when-forced-to-go-in-the-wrong-direction) by pressing up and then down in quick succession causing both tiles to spawn above the rest. Is this intended behavior?

As this question is implementation specific, I'm playing [this](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) version in my computer and [this](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/2048/id840919914?mt=8) version on my iPhone. This occurs in both versions.

Clarification (underscore "_" denotes an empty tile):

What I expect:

```
2 4 2 _  
4 2 _ _  
8 _ _ _  
2 _ _ _
```

Press right (4 spawned)

```
_ 2 4 2  
_ _ 4 2  
_ _ _ 8  
4 _ _ 2
```

Press left (2 spawned)

```
2 4 2 _  
4 2 _ _  
8 _ _ 2  
4 2 _ _
```

What I observed if keys are pressed fast enough:

```
2 4 2 _  
4 2 _ _  
8 _ _ _  
2 _ _ _
```

Press right (nothing spawns)

```
_ 2 4 2  
_ _ 4 2  
_ _ _ 8  
_ _ _ 2
```

Press left fast enough (two tiles spawn)

```
2 4 2 _  
4 2 _ _  
8 _ _ 4  
2 _ _ 2
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I have not been able to reproduce this situation. Is it occurring only when there are absolutely no other moves (but down, for example)? Or does it also happen when you press two keys in rapid succession, but there are other move available as well?

Comment: @Michal To my understanding there is no such thing as this glitch. Try examine your source more closely.